# Pulley on stationary axle

Tags: modifiers, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm new to blender, and for some reason it appears that no one has ever made a simple pulley (at least I couldn't find any forums or videos on it).

I need a very simple pulley on a stationary axle. What I have tried so far is creating the pulley and making it an active rigid body with mesh shape instead of convex hull. Then I put an axle through the center and make it a passive rigid body. Every time I run the simulation, the pulley is EJECTED from frame -- it is launched into oblivion. I figured this means that the meshes are overlapped, but I thought switching the shape type to mesh fixed that. I've tried playing with axle size, scaling the simulation up (I read that blender doesn't like small rigid bodies), and adjusting the rigid body settings to see if it was something stupid.

Blend file on Blend-Exchange:

[image]

Any help is appreciated -- I'm completely lost here.

Answer (score 2):

1. i am pretty sure it is because the messy geometry of your objects.

Here you can see:

[image]

and it should look like this:

[image]

the edges should be parallel.

2. your sensitivity is much too high:

[image]

Set it to 0.

3. set shape to mesh
4. apply scale + rotation

Hint: your objects have too much geometry. This is not necessary and just slow down the rigid body calculation.

i cleaned up your geometry of this part:

[image]

This is, how it should look like.

Result after cleanup of the simulation:

[image]

Note: i had to raise the friction to about 0.8 so that the rigid body simulation worked.